# Two-Sample t-Test for Equal Means with unequal variances for large samples

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, heteroscedasticity

How can I perform a two sample test of means with unequal variances for a very large sample in R?

In case of large samples the statistic will asymptotically follow a normal distribution.

Which R function will help me to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can compute the z-statistic, actually an ordinary Welch t-test will do that just fine - in R that's `t.test` with all its default options.

The form of test statistic is the same in both cases. The only difference is in which table is used, and if the size of the smaller group is large enough, the tests will give almost identical p-values.

The Welch test will handle very large sample sizes.

e.g. in R:

```
> x=rnorm(1e7,1.00001,1)
> y=rnorm(1e7,1.00002,2)
> t.test(x,y)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 0.9052, df = 14708415, p-value = 0.3654
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.0007458214  0.0020259201
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 0.999757  0.999117
```

I don't see a problem

```
> # compare:
> 2*pnorm((-abs(mean(y)-mean(x))/sqrt(var(y)/length(y)+var(x)/length(x))))
[1] 0.3653657
```

The p-values turn out to be the same to all the places shown in the second figure.

If that's not what you want, you need to more carefully explain what you do want.

---

Example with very different $n$:

```
> x=rnorm(1e7,1.00001,1)
> y=rnorm(1e2,1.002,2)
> t.test(x,y)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 0.7382, df = 99.001, p-value = 0.4622
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.2409398  0.5264124
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.9998066 0.8570703 

> 2*pnorm((-abs(mean(y)-mean(x))/sqrt(var(y)/length(y)+var(x)/length(x))))
[1] 0.4604087
```

Once we're at 99df for the Welch, we start to notice a small difference in p-value from the asympotic result, but since we're at 99d.f., we're not really in the 'consider it as converged to normal' region.

Comment: I think this should do it.
So, even if sample sizes of x and y are different there won't be a problem right?

Comment: It depends on just how different they are and how different the variances are -- but if things are such that the t and the z (see the second calculation) don't give the same p-value, I'd be more leery of the z than the t. The Welch-Satterthwaite d.f. should tell you if that's an issue. If that's in the hundreds, it won't make a practical difference unless you're well into the tail.

Comment: could expand on the d.f. part?

Comment: I don't know what you're after. Could you expand on what you want expanded on? (NB added another example with very different $n$)

Comment: I've got what I was looking for. Just want to know how will d.f. help me to know what is the issue. What is the concept behind this

Comment: The only difference between the Welch t-test and the asymptotic test for $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$ is which tables you look up. A t with very high degrees of freedom has very similar p-values to the normal. A t with low degrees of freedom mostly doesn't. If the d.f. in the Welch t-test isn't (as I originally said) "well into the hundreds", the t- and z- won't give identical answers (to say the 3 significant figures most people care about near the significance levels most people care about). But in any case, the asymptotic p-value is in my answer too, so take your pick which you use.

Comment: The point was, if your smallest $n$ is really big, you don't have to go to the effort of typing `2*pnorm((-abs(mean(y)-mean(x))/sqrt(var(y)/length(y)+var(x)/length(x))))` since `t.test(x,y)` will be identical, as near as makes no odds... and when they differ (because the Welch-Satterthwaite d.f. isn't quite big enough), I'd tend to worry more about the $z$ than the $t$.

Answer (score 2):

A few points in addition to what @Glen_b makes.

1) The default in t.test is var.equal = FALSE which means it assumes the samples have different variances.

2) I think it is a useful exercise to just skim over the proof of this result in the case of the z-test (involves Slutsky's theorem and the CLT) which you will find online quite easily. Even if all the steps don't make sense (like convergence in distribution for example) it will give you a good sense for why you really care about these degrees of freedom.